# mysql query how to sum attendance status values

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql. In the above table i have to `SUM attendance_status(column)`  depending on the date like

```
01/05/2013 att_stat=0
01/05/2013 att_stat=1
02/05/2013 att_stat=0
02/05/2013 att_stat=1
```

It's working pretty well when thr is only 3 record when I insert 4th one its not working

```
SELECT SUM(Attendance_Status) as total FROM student_attendance1 Where Attendance_Status='1' and Date= '"+datevalue+"'";'
```

Comment: What should be the outcome?

Comment: can you provide mysql fiddle

Comment: what is the table structure and outcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are close just have to put `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
  SUM(Attendance_Status) AS total
FROM student_attendance1
WHERE Attendance_Status = '1'
    AND DATE = '"+datevalue+"'"
GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: Finally worked thank you sir...SELECT Date,COUNT(Attendance_Status) as total FROM student_attendance1 Where Attendance_Status='0' GROUP BY Date;